# jq built-in method select(): command not found

Tags: shell, select, jq

I used the jq built-in method `select` to parse the json string in shell script, and got an error: `command not found`.

Here is my shell script: `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

function test(){

   json='[{"id":1,"name":"jdjson"},{"id":2,"name":"imagetookit"}]'

   detail=`echo $json | jq .[]|select\(.id==2\)`
}

test
```

I just ran the script on the command line and got the following error:

```
$ bash test.sh
test.sh:行5: select(.id==2): 未找到命令 (means "command not found")
```

the `select` is built-in method of jq command, and I don't know why

Does the function need to be imported? How to import method of jq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a `jq` problem, it's a shell quoting issue:

```
mytest(){
  json='[{"id":1,"name":"jdjson"},{"id":2,"name":"imagetookit"}]'
  detail=$(echo "$json" | jq '.[]|select(.id==2)')
  echo "$detail"
}
mytest
{
   "id": 2,
   "name": "imagetookit"
}
```

Notice the single quote `'` around the `jq` command and so no need for backslash `\`.
Also prefer the `$(...)` instead of the old backtick notation.

Comment: A function name that doesn't override the `test` builtin might be better form. BTW, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete re: function declaration syntax (the `function` keyword is mentioned in two separate tables -- one discussing the hybrid of POSIX and ksh syntax used here (which is compatible with *neither* POSIX *or* ksh), the other discussing the ksh form from which the `function` keyword was taken.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's good info. I took `mytest` as function name to avoid possible problems

Comment: thanks, it solves my problem.  I should have followed the standard grammar